# I have written a code in Android to Post some data into the DRF (Django REST framwork). The server is giving an error message = 400 data is not empty

Tags: android, post, django-rest-framework

I have problem in this function in the DataPackager class.

```
public String packData()
    {
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        StringBuffer packedData=new StringBuffer();

        try
        {
            jo.put("phone_number",phone);
            jo.put("password",password);

            Boolean firstValue=true;
            int last=1;

            Iterator it=jo.keys();

            Log.i("Info :",jo.keys().toString());

            do {
                String key=it.next().toString();
                String value=jo.get(key).toString();

                if(firstValue)
                {
                    firstValue=false;
                    //packedData.append("{");

                }else
                {
                    packedData.append(",");
                    last++;
                }

                //packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append(URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8"));
               // packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append("=");
               // packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));
                //packedData.append('"');

                if (last==2){

                    //packedData.append("}");

                }


            }while (it.hasNext());

            Log.i("Info :",packedData.toString());

            return packedData.toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In my opinion the problem is with the format of json which I am sending to data. I have tried to format in this way

```
{"phone_number"= "8498446545", "password"="1234"}
```

then also sever is rejecting the data. Please help me.

**Is the problem is with formating or with the code?**

MainActivity Starts here it provides data to the Sender class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/*
1.OUR LAUNCHER ACTIVITY
2.INITIALIZE SOME UI STUFF
3.WE START SENDER ON BUTTON CLICK
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String urlAddress="REST api";
    EditText phoneTxt,passwordTxt;
    Button saveBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //INITIALIZE UI FIELDS
        phoneTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
        passwordTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        saveBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //START ASYNC TASK
                Sender s=new 

Sender(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,phoneTxt,passwordTxt);
                    s.execute();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is Sender Class it extends AsyncTask and sends data to DataPackager class

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

/**
 * 1.SEND DATA FROM EDITTEXT OVER THE NETWORK
 * 2.DO IT IN BACKGROUND THREAD
 * 3.READ RESPONSE FROM A SERVER
 */
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    EditText phoneTxt,passwordTxt;

    String phone,password;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    /*
            1.OUR CONSTRUCTOR
    2.RECEIVE CONTEXT,URL ADDRESS AND EDITTEXTS FROM OUR MAINACTIVITY
    */
    public Sender(Context c, String urlAddress,EditText...editTexts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.urlAddress="DRF api";

        //INPUT EDITTEXTS
        this.phoneTxt=editTexts[0];
        this.passwordTxt=editTexts[1];

        //GET TEXTS FROM EDITEXTS
        phone=phoneTxt.getText().toString();
        password=passwordTxt.getText().toString();

    }
    /*
   1.SHOW PROGRESS DIALOG WHILE DOWNLOADING DATA
    */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Send");
        pd.setMessage("Sending..Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }

    /*
    1.WHERE WE SEND DATA TO NETWORK
    2.RETURNS FOR US A STRING
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.send();
    }

    /*
  1. CALLED WHEN JOB IS OVER
  2. WE DISMISS OUR PD
  3.RECEIVE A STRING FROM DOINBACKGROUND
   */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        pd.dismiss();

        if(response != null)
        {
            //SUCCESS
            Toast.makeText(c,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            phoneTxt.setText("");
            passwordTxt.setText("");
        }else
        {
            //NO SUCCESS
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unsuccessful "+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /*
    SEND DATA OVER THE NETWORK
    RECEIVE AND RETURN A RESPONSE
     */
    private String send()
    {
        //CONNECT
        HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);

        if(con==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            Log.i("Info:","Connection is OK");
            OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream();

            //WRITE
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            bw.write(new DataPackager(phone,password).packData());
            Log.i("Info:","Connection is OK2222222222222");

            bw.flush();

            //RELEASE RES
            bw.close();
            os.close();

            //HAS IT BEEN SUCCESSFUL?
            int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("Response Code:",Integer.toString(responseCode));

            if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK)
            {
                //GET EXACT RESPONSE
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();
                Log.i("Info:","Connection is OK3333333333333333333333");

                String line;

                //READ LINE BY LINE
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                //RELEASE RES
                br.close();

                return response.toString();

            }else
            {
                Log.i("ERROR : ","awerstdhyigutfdrerdyugiugtfdreyuggtrdedyg");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is DataPackager class this packes the data into json format and sends it to connection

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * 1.BASICALLY PACKS DATA WE WANNA SEND
 */
public class DataPackager {

    String phone,password;

    /*
    SECTION 1.RECEIVE ALL DATA WE WANNA SEND
     */
    public DataPackager(String phone, String password) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.password = password;
        Log.i("Info :",this.phone+"         "+this.password);
    }

    /*
   SECTION 2
   1.PACK THEM INTO A JSON OBJECT
   1. READ ALL THIS DATA AND ENCODE IT INTO A FROMAT THAT CAN BE SENT VIA NETWORK
    */
    public String packData()
    {
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        StringBuffer packedData=new StringBuffer();

        try
        {
            jo.put("phone_number",phone);
            jo.put("password",password);

            Boolean firstValue=true;
            int last=1;

            Iterator it=jo.keys();

            Log.i("Info :",jo.keys().toString());

            do {
                String key=it.next().toString();
                String value=jo.get(key).toString();

                if(firstValue)
                {
                    firstValue=false;
                    //packedData.append("{");

                }else
                {
                    packedData.append(",");
                    last++;
                }

                //packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append(URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8"));
               // packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append("=");
               // packedData.append('"');
                packedData.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));
                //packedData.append('"');

                if (last==2){

                    //packedData.append("}");

                }


            }while (it.hasNext());

            Log.i("Info :",packedData.toString());

            return packedData.toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is Connector class this sends the data from the DataPackager class and check the status whether data is received or not. Here I am getting code 400 in logs. Which specifies no data is sent. which is not true I am sending the data.

```
package com.iyer.post;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Connector {

    /*
    1.SHALL HELP US ESTABLISH A CONNECTION TO THE NETWORK
    1. WE ARE MAKING A POST REQUEST
    */
    public static HttpURLConnection connect(String urlAddress) {

        try
        {
            URL url=new URL(urlAddress);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //SET PROPERTIES
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            con.setReadTimeout(20000);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            //RETURN
            return con;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: this seems a GET api when i access given url from browser it returns data instantly, like the whole approach is wrong its showing everything without authentication. m not sure whats your requirement is but clearly this is not the way  You implement APIs. and on Android use library like Retrofit/volley for API calls. Your request json also not valid.

Comment: If you send data in JSON format arrange it as so. {"data": "value", "data2": "value2"}